# What are the forms of KVC (NSKeyValueCoding) in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, kvc

Some methods within `NSKeyValueCoding` can refer to specialized methods of the class that are named based on the property's name.  (For instance, working on the key "`testers`" during `- validateValue: forKey: error:` would look for a method called `- validateTesters: error:`.)  How does this work in Swift?  This is important, since `NSKeyValueCoding` is an informal protocol, because getting the name and/or signature wrong for one of these methods won't cause a compiler error, but have the method ignored and getting the default behavior instead (which may be worse).

Comment: It works as per obj-c, because it's obj-c that does it

Comment: @Wain, I'm asking what the method prototypes are (i.e. what do I type in the text editor if I'm using Swift instead of Objective-C).

Comment: you can see more about runtime in objc .  in swift will use Reflection ,but it's not strong enough

Comment: @WilsonXJ, I'm not asking on how it's implemented (I don't care.), just how to write the function's name and signature down in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking advantage of the dynamic nature of ObjC. To demonstrate how it's done, let's walk through an example:

Define a class that inherits from `NSObject` and thus can make use of the ObjC run time:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    func validateFirstName(value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws {
        guard let firstName = value.memory as? String else {
            // You can decide to throw an error or not here
            return
        }

        if firstName == "Jack" {
            throw NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "I don't like the firstName Jack"])
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
let p = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith")

var newFirstName: AnyObject? = "Jack"
var newLastName: AnyObject? = "Johnson"

do {
    try p.validateValue(&newFirstName, forKey: "firstName")

    // This line will not execute if newFirstName == "Jack"
    print("No problem validating firstName")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

do {
    try p.validateValue(&newLastName, forKey: "lastName")
    print("No problem validating lastName")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I don't care how Apple implements it, just what the function's name format and signature are.  It's just because the guide, which does give those for Objective-C, hasn't been updated for Swift (yet).